# Using Graph API Explorer gets friends list but my own app doesn't . (Graph API Explorer token v.s App Token)

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my friends list in my app. If I use the access token in my Graph API Explorer console and hit the url. https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me?access_token='GraphAPIToken'. I am able to get the complete friends list. If I try using the SDK or any library like fbgraph for nodejs I just get the summary which contains the count.  I know that with ^v2.0 I have access only to taggable_friends or invitable_friends. My question is that why can the complete friends list be obtained only by Graph API Explorer Token and not any other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the whole friends list anymore, even with Graph API Explorer (with chosen version >=2.0). That's just not correct that this is possible.

Furthermore, there is no such thing as *Graph API Explorer Token*. There are either

- App
- User
- Page
- Client

Access Tokens. From where you get those is not relevant.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 1):

The friends you see in the response have used the Graph API Explorer as well.

> In order for a person to show up in one person's friend list, both people must have decided to share their list of friends with your app and not disabled that permission during login. Also both friends must have been asked for user_friends during the login process.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_friends